# Push bare repo contents to another

Tags: git

We have remotes external and internal. Due to security-related network restrictions most of the devs have access to external and only some have access to internal. There are few people with access to both.

I want to push updates in external to internal periodically, what git command do I use? I know there is `git fetch --bare` for grabbing the changes but we don't command line access to internal. At this time I'm fairly certain that external and internal are not mirrors of each other, but I believe this is something we can change if it makes a simpler solution.

Comment: Does `git push external <branchname>` not work? If so, is it because both have a different commit history?

Comment: Maybe? Depends on how much bare repos are like real repos. TBH they seem kind of exotic to me but I can give it a shot. I didn't think to look more closely at the `git push` man page as a result. I think `git push --mirror --all external` fits my use case.